# Search twitter API code-js

Tags: javascript, twitter

I need to use Twitter's Search API. I read twitter's developer documentation and it says that client side authentication is not recommended anymore. But, since mine is really a small application and on a very tight deadline, I decided to use codebird-js.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sha1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="codebird.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function loginTwitter() {
 var cb = new Codebird();
 cb.setConsumerKey("my_consumer_key","my_consumer_secret");
 cb.setToken("my_token", "my_token_secret");
 cb.__call(
  "search_tweets",
  "q=Twitter",
   function (reply) {
   alert("hey");
 },
 true
 );
}

</script>
```

Dont think there is any problem with the callback of  search tweets, since this is what is documented in codebird-js.Kindly suggest any alternatives to make the code work.
Also, I enabled the option "Allow application to sign in with twitter" in application settings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some syntax corrections to your code and to call the "loginTwitter()" function; the code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sha1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="codebird.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loginTwitter() {
    var cb = new Codebird();
    cb.setConsumerKey("my_consumer_key", "my_consumer_secret");
    cb.setToken("my_token", "my_token_secret");

    cb.__call(
        "search_tweets",
        "q=Twitter",
        function (reply) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(reply));  //do something with the result
        },
        true
    );
};

loginTwitter();

</script>
```

And don't forget to download the codebird for javascript and put its files into the same folder as your main file (according to the path that you have put in your script).